# Zoom al mantener presionado un input en fluter

Tags: flutter

necesito un poco de ayuda con algo... espero puedan darme una idea de como darle solución

Tengo una pantalla de login con los usuales textformfield email y password. Haciendo pruebas en mi móvil, al mantener presionado sobre un input para elegir la opción pegar, hace un zoom del texto del input, del hintText. Dejo el código del textfieldform.

```js
TextFormField(
            autocorrect: false,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Email',
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))
              ),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 8)
            ),
            onChanged: ( value ) => email = value,
            validator: ( value ) {

                String pattern = r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
                RegExp regExp  = RegExp(pattern);
                
                return regExp.hasMatch(value ?? '')
                  ? null
                  : 'Invalid e-mail address';

            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa la propiedad  **readOnly**

> Cuando se establece en true, el texto no se puede modificar
> mediante ningún método abreviado ni operación del teclado. El texto
> sigue siendo seleccionable.

Realiza el siguiente cambio aplicando la propiedad `readOnly` :

```
TextFormField(
            readOnly: true,
            autocorrect: false,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Email',
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))
              ),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 8)
            ),
            onChanged: ( value ) => email = value,
            validator: ( value ) {

                String pattern = r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
                RegExp regExp  = RegExp(pattern);
                
                return regExp.hasMatch(value ?? '')
                  ? null
                  : 'Invalid e-mail address';

            },
          ),
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, el problema con usar readonly es que no se puede escribir en el input y si necesito que puedan escribir

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una solución al problema, lo que sucede es, al mantener presionado sobre un input, se muestra una burbuja como mostrando un zoom del input, si el input tiene datos o un hintText, muestra eso, si esta vacío, muestra la burbuja vacía, la solución fue agregar el siguiente código en cada input:

```js
magnifierConfiguration: TextMagnifierConfiguration(
              shouldDisplayHandlesInMagnifier: false,
              magnifierBuilder: (
                  BuildContext context,
                  MagnifierController controller,
                  ValueNotifier<MagnifierInfo> magnifierInfo,
              ) { return null; },
            ),
```